# Images do not appear on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, desktop

**1. Edit after answers:** From what I understand, my phone's security software is blocking my html document from accessing local files. If so, I understand. Actually, I am trying to make a shopping list application that can work offline. Is it possible to work offline with images?

---

I can see the images when I open my Html file, which is in the same folder with the images, on my desktop computer. When I transfer the project to my phone and open it, the images do not appear. What is the problem?

This is working on my desktop. Creating all elements and images successfully but doesn't work in my phone. I think it is about folder path but still don't know how. Thank you.

```
if (listitem.length != 0) {
    // Create Container For New List
    let crtcon = document.createElement("div");
    crtcon.className = "listelementcon";
    mylists.appendChild(crtcon);

    // Create New List Elements
    let listdiv = document.createElement("div");
    let listbtn = document.createElement("button");
    listbtn.id = `list${i}plus`;
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "blue-circle.png";
    listbtn.appendChild(image);

    let removebtn = document.createElement("button");
    const image2 = document.createElement("img");
    image2.src = "bin.png";
    removebtn.appendChild(image2);
    removebtn.addEventListener("click", removelist);

    listdiv.innerHTML = listitem[0];
    listdiv.className = "listelement";

    crtcon.appendChild(listbtn);
    crtcon.appendChild(listdiv);
    crtcon.appendChild(removebtn);
}
```

I tried to open my project on my phone but I failed on my images.

Comment: How are you transferring the code and images to your iPhone?

Comment: Just copy and paste by USB. I pasted them in the "download" folder. My phone is Samsung Galaxy A04s.

Comment: Have you thought about making a localhost server with node.js and then opening it in your phone? It would be much more efficient ... [here's a quick tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/expressjs-web-application)

Comment: There is no guarantee your phone has the same allowance as a desktop when reading files from the `file://` protocol. If you want to test websites, follow @KārlisKazāks advice and spin up a local server so you can get the _actual_ experience on a site. The `file://` protocol has _many_ restrictions, mostly to prevent websites from trying to access your computer, which would be a _terrible_ idea for privacy and safety.

Comment: My English is weak. From what I understand, my phone's security software is blocking my html document from accessing local files. If so, I understand. Actually, I am trying to make a shopping list application that can work offline. Is it possible to work offline with images?

Comment: @DenizUnal you don't need wifi to use the solution i gave you. I can make a quick answer with the code you need to make the `localserver`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test your website on a phone would be through a `localserver` or `localhost` here's a quick way to make it through the use of [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en) and `ExpressJs`

Firstly install [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en) and in the same directory you have your website run this command.

```
npm install express
```

Place all the files that you have from the website and place them in a new folder called `public`

Afterwards create a file named `index.js` and write this code inside:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.use("/", express.static('public'))


app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("Running on http://localhost:3000")})
```

and if everything went alright you should be able to find the website on your computer or phone when entering `http://localhost:3000/`, (make sure your primary html file is named `index.html` if not name it that) but your phone has to be on the same wifi as the machine you are running the server on

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this when I able.